# Inno Setup Silent Installation

Tags: installation, inno-setup, uninstallation, silent

We are working on creating Setup File which can install and uninstall silently without any user intervention

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters:/VERYSILENT; Flags: nowait
```

Still getting Message Box for selecting destination location and create desktop icon for user. Please help

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create an installer that runs completelly silently on its own when executed/double-clicked?

Answer (score 2):

Is it a third-party setup you are running? You can set `/SP-`, `/NOICONS`, and `/DIR="x:\dirname"` parameters then.

If it is your own setup, there are several dialogs you can disable in the `[Setup]` section:

```
DisableStartupPrompt=yes
DisableDirPage=yes
```

For all directives see the [online help](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/)